# Large z-score values

Tags: sas, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, k-means

We was working on large datasets of telecom. when we standardized the data we’ve got big z-score it varies from -0.xxx to 300 or 400! 
These attributes has for exemple min=0 and Max about 4,000,000 
Yes somes variables has outliers. We’ll this have good results for clustering without dealing with outliers?

The results of the proc fastclus with 8 cluster lead to grouped cluster (the seventh has 1,600,000 observations) there one too with 1 observation.

What’s our problem?

https://medium.com/p/6b6056224c54/info?source=email-75f4ab5a8577-1529361861973-activity.response_createdhttps://medium.com/p/6b6056224c54/info?source=email-75f4ab5a8577-1529361861973-activity.response_created

Comment: Can you add one or several histograms? The link you added requires subscription.

Comment: (Btw you'd probably get more attention for this on Cross-Validated)

Comment: @JasonV look at this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352080/transform-heavy-right-tailed-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables likely are very **skewed**.

The use of z standardization on such variables is questionable. You probably should look into box-cox transformations, too.

Comment: Thanks, but does log transformation to can handle it? look at this to see my distributions variables(all others are like that)    

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352080/transform-heavy-right-tailed-data

Comment: A log transformation may or may not be good enough. It's worth a try.

Comment: ok thanks. In case a do it with log, is it compulsory to transform all continuous variables or only these which are long tailed?

Comment: Don't blindly apply transformations. That is why you should try box-cox. It helps you evaluate when to use such a transformation and when not.